# map with vector as key operation find

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I have a:`map<vector<int>, vector<int>> info`

I have to do a search.
I try:

```
Key[0]=1;
Key[1]=3;
Key[2]=1;
test=info.find(key);
```

Where `Key` and `test` are defined as follows:`vector<int> Key (3,0)` and `vector<int> test (2,0)`.

But this returns a compilation error: `error: no match for 'operator=' in 'test =`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Hi,  can I ask why you are using a vector as the key?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? A compile error? In that case, what's the error? Or failure to find something you think it should find? In that case, what have you put into `info` and how? Or something else?

Comment: @GMasucci: To map sequences of numbers to other sequences of numbers. Why else?

Comment: You never use test above you also do not say what is  not working

Comment: `std::map::find` returns iterator, but not value. You should dereference iterator, or do something like `test = info[key];`.

Comment: Is a compiler error. error: no match for 'operator=' in 'test = ...

Comment: @vincentdj you should put the compiler error in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` returns an iterator.  First you need to check if the key was actually found, by testing it against `info.end()`.  Then, you need to assign from the value, which is stored in the second of the pair.

```
auto it = info.find(key);
// pre-c++11: std::map<vector<int>, vector<int> >::iterator it = info.find(key)
if (it != info.end())
{
    test = it->second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because `std::vector` does not have an operator overload for iterator assignment.

`std::vector<int>::find` returns an input iterator. `std::vector<int>::operator=` takes another `std::vector<int>` or a C++11 initializer-list.

You should try something like this instead.

```
// Some map.
std::map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> info{ { { 1, 3, 1 }, { 5, 5, 5 } } };

auto itr = info.find({ 1, 3, 1 }); // Find element
if (itr != std::end(info)) {       // Only if found
    auto& v = itr->second;         // Iterator returns std::pair (key, value)
    for (auto i : v) {             // Print result or do what you want.
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```